# Provisioning new accounts with template data across accounts

Tags: google-apps-script

When a new user accepts an invitation for a new account to use my program by clicking a URL I have to accomplish in script:

copy data from a template spreadsheet to a new spreadsheet for the new user

There are several conditions to work around:
 - the template spreadsheet to copy resides in the administrative account 
 - the web app for the user is configured to log with the user's account, not my administrative account

I am struggling with how to read and copy the template spreadsheet data while logged into the user's account? As Google Apps has no scriptable interface for accessing a spreadsheet from a different account..even though the user will have read privilege to the template spreadsheet.

I have contemplated different ideas but am not sure..can I chain web apps together and pass data between web apps accessed from different accounts? Or, do I have to script a totally new data store  other than spreadsheets and Google Drive? The new data store would have to be accessible from both the administrative account and a user's account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you program is a GAS WebApp, then deploy it from your admin account with settings:

**Execute the app as:** me (admin.account@yourdomain.com)

**Who has access to the app:** Anyone

This way the server-side code of your app will run under admin account, and will have access to your template spreadsheet, and signed-in users will be able to interface with the client-side of your app. You may have to implement some user authorization in your app, so only specific users who received an invitation are allowed to access it. For example, you can store users' email addresses in a sheet in your admin template spreadsheet, and check if current use is in the list before creating an account for the user. Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() will give you current active user's email address. Similarly you can check if an active user already has an account created.

If your program is not a GAS WebApp - please edit your question to add more pertinent details.

Comment: still appreciate the input but Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() only works if the web app is set to "Execute as the User" otherwise  getEmail() only returns a blank string if "Execute as Myself" is set and I cannot tell who the user is.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() will return user's email IF the owner of the script and the user are in the same Google Apps Domain. However, if you deploy your app from a generic (non-domain) Google account (i.e. someone@gmail.com), it will return an empty string. I was under the impression you were working in a domain account, though you did not explicitly say so in your question.

Comment: Thanks, no worries, I'd like anyone on the internet to be able to use the app...I would use "Execute as Myself" and pass the user their URL with the email address as a parm but that would be a Massive security hole as anyone able to spoof the URL can gain access to admin and other user's data.  I'd like to keep GAS as the GUI of course but am also checking into Google Cloud Store for the backend. And, still have to figure out how to call Google Cloud Store from GAS-UiApp if you have any ideas on that would be very helpful.

Comment: In that case consider using and alternative datastore. I like using [Parse.com](http://parse.com), but you can use pretty much any database, as long as it is publicly accessible (not behind firewall), using [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/). Your server-side script will interface with your datastore using connection setting or API keys, so will work even in an app executing as 'User accessing the webapp'.

Comment: Thank again..I think they are probably the best answers at this point.